# make a get ajax from jquery until the files exists

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get, listener

I want to make an AJAX call to a file on a server, from jQuery ...

The problem is that this file is generated when I do a post from another pc / browser.

What I want is that the request still listening, until the file is generated, and do not return a 404 response...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a server-side script which will wait until the file exists, then return its contents.  (or redirect to the file)

Comment: I think the solution could be a socket in the server... but... how to make a socket in ruby, i dont find anything in google :/

Comment: @Pablo: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: i dont find a "nice" way to wait until the file exists, i think about a notification from the server to the client...

Comment: I mean, I think that the best way, is that the server tell the client when to find the file, to an open channel... its not a socket??

Comment: You can't do that on the client (except for HTML5 WebSockets). You can just use a single long-running request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` to repeatedly check, if the response has been 200, positive. You can adjust the timeout value to balance the load on the server and the UI experience. Also, if everything fails, a counter could limit the number of total tries.

Comment: but the server will receive a lot of innecesary requests :/

Comment: Not necessarily; if e.g. on average a file is ready for download in 0.85s, then you can let the javascript get the file after one second, which in most cases should result in a STATUS_OK, 200. If something goes wrong, you could increase the timeout by a factor of two: the js would ask for the file after 1s, 2s, 4s, 8s, etc. up to a maximum. This way you would only request each file for at most 5 times, if we say the maximum would be 30s.

Comment: mmm... yep, but i mean i could take 3 hours maybe... i wanna to open a port and let the server send a notification to the client when could find the file, and just make one correctly request... 

but i dont know how to do it on Ruby on Rails :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you're asking.  Best bet would probably be to put the Ajax call in a `while` loop to just poll the server until it returns the file.

Comment: A `while` loop won't help.  You need to use the callback.

Comment: with a while it works, but i dont wanna make thousands of request :/